# Redirect user after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a logout system, in c# logout work properly but in frontend when I click on the logout button, the isLogged variable is changed in the database in 0 of 1 (as it should be) but in the browser the user is not redirected to the login page and i get error " Requested JSON parse failed "

i try to make ajax call to work properly, i search on this site solution but i can t fix this problem

```
 var userAIDI = window.localStorage.getItem('userId');
    console.log(userAIDI)
    var usr = {
        userId:userAIDI
    }
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:44378/api/userLogOut",
        data: JSON.stringify(usr),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = "pages/login.html";


            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            alert(msg);
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the .html extension.

Browsers tend to keep a cache of .html for longer time in browsing history. Try to test the feature in incognito tab in google chrome, or try to convert all files to .asp or .php (whichever you are using).

I am suggesting this because your code looks fine, and the database is also reflecting properly, as suggested by you here:

*" the isLogged variable is changed in the database in 0 of 1 (as it should be) but in the browser, the user is not redirected to the login page" .*

Comment: There is a comma, in the second last line, is that required?

Comment: i solve the problem, i changed "json" in " text" and redirect works properly

Answer (score 0):

Something in the backend might be throwing an exception after the database manipulation Thus, everything seems to ok in the database. 
I advice you to run the debuger backend and follow the data that´s being posted. Alternatively post some of the most significant code here.